# Symfony: How to encrypt/decrypt route parameters automatically?

Tags: php, symfony, encryption

I'd like to **en-/decrypt parameters** *(e.g. IDs)* in the URL/route **automatically**, example:

`domain.com/item/show/1` should look like `domain.com/item/show/uj7hs2`.

**Current (pseudo-)code**

```
public function myControllerFunctionAction() {
    // ...
    $id = $this->get('my.crypt')->encrypt($item->getId());
    return $this->redirectToRoute('routeTo_myOtherControllerAction', array('id' => $id));
}

public function myOtherControllerFunctionAction($id) {
    $id = $this->get('my.crypt')->decrypt($id); // decrypt

    $item = $this->get('my.repository')->find($id);
    // ...
}
```

I'd like to **avoid manually en-/decrypting**.

Something like this would be perfect:

```
# routing.yml
routeTo_myOtherControllerAction:
    path:     /item/show/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: appBundle:Items:show }
    options:
        crypt_auto: true
        crypt_method: %default_crypt_method%
```

I couldn't find any other solution than my service yet. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, just to clarify:

1. You want to obfuscate the database record ID (i.e. primary key)?
2. You want the resulting URL to be short.

If you answered "yes" to both questions, consider following this [guide to URL parameter encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php).

#### What People Want To Do Here

[image: Some encryption function is used to deterministically retrieve the ID]

#### What People Should Do Instead

[image: Use a separate column]

#### What if I'm Okay with Longer URLs?

Use [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption). It provides [authenticated encryption](http://tonyarcieri.com/all-the-crypto-code-youve-ever-written-is-probably-broken) and is one of the most well studied PHP encryption libraries available. (It's also permissively licensed.)

```
$decrypted = Crypto::decrypt($urlParameter, $yourKey);
// ... snip ... //
echo "<a href=\"/your/url/?".http_build_query([
    'id' => Crypto::encrypt($yourRowId, $yourKey)
])."\">";
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with [NzoUrlEncryptorBundle](https://github.com/NAYZO/NzoUrlEncryptorBundle) which is what I used for same reason. I'm just giving you examples below referencing to the its readme file. You can have a look at it for more details.

Features include:

- Url Data & parameters Encryption
- Url Data & parameters Decryption
- Data Encryption & Decryption
- Access from Twig by ease
- Flexible configuration

**routing.yml**

```
my-path-in-the-routing:
    path: /my-url/{id}
    defaults: {_controller: MyBundle:MyController:MyFunction}
```

**In the controller with annotation service**

```
use Nzo\UrlEncryptorBundle\Annotations\ParamDecryptor;
//...

    /**
     * @ParamDecryptor(params="id, toto, bar")
     */
     public function indexAction(User $id, $toto) 
    {
        // no need to use the decryption service here as the parameters are already decrypted by the annotation service.
        //....

    }
```

**In the controller without annotation service:**

```
public function indexAction($id) 
{
    $MyId = $this->get('nzo_url_encryptor')->decrypt($id);

    //....

}

 public function indexAction() 
{   
    //....

    $Encrypted = $this->get('nzo_url_encryptor')->encrypt($data);

    //....

}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, also with Symfony 3.2.

Comment: …out of a few deprecated warnings when using the UrlEncrypterBundle with PHP7.1. See [`mcrypt_module_open`](http://php.net/mcrypt_module_open) for instance. This one has been deprecated as of PHP 7.1 like many other functions of the mcrypt package. Use with care if you are always up-to-date on your development and production environments.